# Android MediaPlayer onPause()

Tags: java, android

I´m a begginer developer for Android and i want to develop a basic app that start music when its opened and stop when its finished (onPause).
When i create a method "onPause", my condition "musica.stop();" don´t work.

My code:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer mpBtnsom = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.somvoa);
        ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        MediaPlayer musica = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sommusica);
        musica.start();
        musica.setLooping(true);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mpBtnsom.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void toast2(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Botão ToastMessage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    public void toast(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Botão Felpudo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        musica.stop();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @OneWay, I thought the annotation isn't mandatory, its because "compilers are required to generate an error message" if certain conditions weren't met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that variable **musica** is not reachable in your **onPause()** method. You should declare you variable **musica** for global use in the class like shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MediaPlayer musica;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer mpBtnsom = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.somvoa);
        ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        musica = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sommusica);
        musica.start();
        musica.setLooping(true);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mpBtnsom.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void toast2(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Botão ToastMessage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    public void toast(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Botão Felpudo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        musica.stop();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should remove finish(), unless you want to end the activity.